# Is it possible to prove that every point on the circle can be expressed as $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ using this approach?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume the IVP or powerseries definitions of $\sin$ and $\cos$ for this question.

It's a basic geometric fact that:

> **Theorem.** Given a pair $(x,y)$ of real numbers, the following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\exists \theta \in \mathbb{R}(x = \cos \theta \wedge y = \sin \theta)$
> 2. $x^2+y^2 = 1$

However, proving this rigorously seems to be rather non-trivial. The direction  $(1) \rightarrow (2)$ is straightforward; it's equivalent to $\cos^2\theta +\sin^2\theta = 1,$ which can itself be proved by differentiating $\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2\theta$ and obtaining $0$, thereby showing that it's a constant function. However, showing $(2) \rightarrow (1)$ seems to be much harder. One idea I had was to first show that the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ defines a smooth $1$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We can then use:

> **Conjecture.** Let $\gamma : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow X$ denote a path in a connected $1$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with constant non-zero speed. Then $\gamma$ is surjective.

My questions are twofold:

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Is this even true?
>
> **Q1.** If so, are there generalizations to the case where the domain of $\gamma$ is replaced by $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: What part of (2) $\implies$ (1) is so difficult that we need to generalize to "a connected $1$-dimensional Riemannian manifold"?  E.g. one might show every point on the unit circle in the first quadrant has the form $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ for unique $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$ and conclude "by symmetry" that the parameterization extends to the other quadrants.

Comment: @hardmath, how would you show that the first quadrant is covered?

Comment: @goblin: Sorry, I wasn't thinking. The reparametrization will also change the domain.

Comment: @levap, that's okay. Shit happens :)

Comment: Since you asked if your approach "works", I'll Comment that for $(x,y)$ on the unit circle in the first quadrant, there must exist $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$ s.t. $x = \cos \theta$ by the IVP (cosine being differentiable, so continuous, and $\cos 0 = 1, \cos \pi/2 = 0$).  Then by the sign restrictions in the first quadrant, the identity $\cos^2 \theta+ \sin^2 \theta = 1$ forces $y = \sin \theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a proof sketch of your conjecture.

Let $A$ be the image of $\gamma$ and $B$ its complement. Suppose $B$ is nonempty.

Since $X$ is connected, there exists a point $P \in \overline{A} \cap \overline{B}$.

Let $U$ be any neighborhood of $P$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

$U$ must contain a point of $A$ and a point of $B$.

The *closed* interval from $A$ to $B$ must have finite length, and thus $\gamma$ traverses the interval from $A$ to $B$ in finite time, and consequently it passes through $B$, giving a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

The geometrical angle bisector is the line through $(x,y)+(1,0)=(x+1,y)$. This ray has $$\frac{(x+1,y)}{\sqrt{2+2x}}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+1}2},\frac{y}{\sqrt{2(x+1)}}\right)$$ as its point on the unit circle. The sequence of angle bisectors $(x_0,y_0)=(x,y)$, $$(x_{n+1},y_{n+1})=\frac{(x_n+1,y_n)}{\sqrt{2+2x_n}}$$
converges to $(1,0)$ and will thus reach a neighborhood of that point where you can easily prove that it is covered by the definitions of the trigonometric functions around $θ=0$.